# I can only get a capital P with caps lock on, mid-2014 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

So, when I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and hit <kbd>p</kbd>,nothing happens. If I select <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and then <kbd>p</kbd>, I get a capital "P".

What gives?  I've looked in System Preferences and don't see that key combination as a shortcut.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the problem only with "P" or does it happen anywhere else?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC?

Comment: It's only the P.  It's the weirdest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: What's the SMC??

Comment: Nevermind.  I just looked it up.  I'll try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to reset both your SMC and NVRAM.

**[Reset NVRAM]**

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**[Reset SMC]**

To reset the SMC on a Mid-2014 MBP follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer

   2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
   3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
   4. Let go
   5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.